# How to catch undefined route on client side in front-end?

Tags: javascript, routes

I'm trying to catch all **undefined route** on the client side in front-end. The front-end is pure **Javascript**.
I've defined component (HTML document) Object with **Class**.

```
class SignIn {
   render() {
     return (
       `<div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="button" value="Signin">
        </div>`
     )
   }
}
```

And the render object is:

```
Route({ render: Signin, exact: true, path: '/signin' });
// default route
Route({ render: PageNotFound, path: '/*' });
```

It's working without **pageNotFound Route**, but catching **undefined routes** causes all **defined routes** to disappear and **a default route** responding to all routes.

This is the **route object**

```
   const rootDocument = document.querySelector('#root');

   export function Route(props) {
    const { render, path, exact } = props;
    const component = new render();
    if (exact && path !== '/*') {
      if (path === url.pathname) {
        rootDocument.innerHTML = component.render();
      }
    } else {
      rootDocument.innerHTML = component.render();
    }
  }
```

NB: It's a **Reacts concept**  but **not React**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually solves it but I think there should be an elegant way of doing it.

```
    const rootDocument = document.querySelector('#root');
    const isContent = document.querySelector('#root');
    const url = location;
    const Router_url = {};

    export function Route(props) {
      const { path, exact } = props;
      Router_url[path] = { render: props.render }; // add to path object
      Object.keys(Router_url).find((el) => {
        if (el === url.pathname && exact && el !== '/*') {
          const { render } = Router_url[el];
          const component = new render();
          rootDocument.innerHTML = component.render();
        } else if (el === '/*' && isContent.children.length === 0) {
          const { render } = Router_url['/*'];
          const component = new render();
          setTimeout(() => {
            rootDocument.innerHTML = component.render();
          }, 500);
        }
      });
    }
```